# ipython on readonly filesystem: "No usable temporary directory found"

Tags: python, directory, ipython, readonly, temporary

if I start IPython on a readonly filesystem it always crashes with:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 217, in _get_default_tempdir
    ("No usable temporary directory found in %s" % dirlist))
IOError: [Errno 2] No usable temporary directory found in ['/tmp', '/var/tmp',
```

For some reasons i can not mount them writeable, so my question:

is it possible to start IPython in a read-only mode?

thanks in advance

preareac

Answer (score 0):

I am looking at the `ipython` config file to see if there's anything about automatic writing and how to turn it off.

One that thing it does, by default, is write a `history.sqlite` file.

Setting:

```
c.HistoryManager.enabled = False
```

might turn that off.  But that requires editing the config file.  But it is possible to change config values like this in the commandline.  I haven't tried that.

```
ipython --HistoryManager.enabled=False
```

might do the trick.

Look at the big help to see if anything looks like it might help.

```
ipython --help-all
```